# Is Hunspell thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, spell-checking, hunspell

Is the Hunspell spelling library thread-safe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is NO, 
A simple multi-threaded test application revealed that Hunspell uses per-instance resources for the spelling process, so only one thread can use it at any time - use locks/work queue/or instanciate a per-thread Hunspell instance.

Comment: You might the following article useful: [Spell Check, Hyphenation, and Thesaurus for .NET with C# and VB Samples - Part 2: Multi Threading](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/spell-check-asp-net-web.aspx).

Comment: And use the latest NHunspell versions from sourceforge, because there are som multithreading bugs in the older versions.

Comment: The current comments for this answer refer to NHunspell, where as the question refers to Hunspell. The different HunSpell implementations have different owners and vary in their implementation.