# Is NHunspell thread safe?

Tags: .net, nhunspell

Is the NHunspell spelling library thread-safe?

On NHunspell's [home page](http://www.crawler-lib.net/csharp-code-samples-nhunspell) it reads "Keep in mind that the Hunspell object is not thread safe." However, may be there is an alternative thread-safe class in the library?

For clarity, this question refers to the .NET variant of Hunspell.

Comment: Please note I'm adding this question as a useful reference because currently a Google Search for "is nhunspell thread safe" takes you to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639789/is-hunspell-thread-safe), which is actually about Hunspell not NHunspell, and gives the answer no.

Comment: Sorry I haven't had the time to put the mulithrading samples on the homepage. As mentioned in the answer I've written an article on CodeProject how to use NHunspell in multithreaded scenarios.

Please pay attention to the memory usage problem described in this question:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43769/Spell-Check-Hyphenation-and-Thesaurus-for-NET-wi?msg=4952267#xx4952267xx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES but only *IF* you use the SpellEngine and SpellFactory classes:

- [SpellEngine page from the API Documentation](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/NHunspell/NHunspell/SpellEngine)
- [Spell Check,
  Hyphenation, and Thesaurus for .NET with C# and VB Samples - Part 2:
  Multi Threading.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/spell-check-asp-net-web.aspx)

Comment: Supplement: The Hunspell, Hyphen and MyThes classes aren't thread save.